# Spark resolved attribute missing following join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am seeing a spark/sql.AnalysisException when joining Dataframes/set which themselves are the result of previous joins

```
    case class Left(a: Int, b: String, c: Boolean)

    case class Right(a: Int, b: String, c: Int)

    // Boilerplate

    import spark.implicits._

    val left = Seq(
      Left(1, "1", true),
      Left(2, "2", true),
      Left(3, "3", true)
    ).toDF

    val right = Seq(
      Right(1, "1", 1),
      Right(2, "2", 2),
      Right(3, "3", 3)
    ).toDF

    val joined1 = left
      .join(right, left("a") === right("a"), "inner")
      .select(left("a"), right("b"), left("c"))

    val joined2 = joined1
      .join(left, joined1("b") === left("b"))
```

The actual error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) b#4 missing from b#49,b#15,c#5,a#48,c#50,a#3 in operator !Join Inner, (b#15 = b#4);;
!Join Inner, (b#15 = b#4)
:- Project [a#3, b#15, c#5]
:  +- Join Inner, (a#3 = a#14)
:     :- LocalRelation [a#3, b#4, c#5]
:     +- LocalRelation [a#14, b#15, c#16]
+- LocalRelation [a#48, b#49, c#50]
```

So I guess the issue is that the columns in joined2 are expressed in terms of the columns from the parent tables and joined1("b"), i.e. b#4 does not exist.

I understand that this is soluble by aliasing the tables and referring to columns as functions.column("leftAlias.column") however I want to pour the result back into a Dataset so I would presumably have to re-rename the columns before doing so.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant solution/workaround?

Many thanks

Terry

Comment: It might not sound like this, based on the title, but it is the same category of problem, and can be solved with the same methods.